# Setting innerHtml of a selection box in IE

Tags: javascript

On my website there is a situation where I need to append new < //option> tags to a specific selection box. I am doing the following:

1.Make an ajax request which returns option tags like

```
 <option>one</option>

 <option>two</option>
```

etc.,

2.Set the inner html of a specific selection box by

```
 document.getElementById("id").innerHTML=response;
```

it works well in firefox/chrome but not in IE....

any known solution for this..??

Comment: never figured out why it doesnt work in ie thats why i use jquery

Comment: Check once what exactly you are getting using console.log in chrome , try appendChild to append into "id"

Comment: @lbu : i too used jquery to get rid of this problem..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a known IE bug. You can either user DOM methods to append/replace the option elements, or you can use [the workarounds suggested by Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228), one of which is to wrap your select in a div and set the div's innerHTML to "<select><option>..."

Comment: +1 there was a time where i struggled to get this to work, thank you for valuable info

Comment: +1. yep, a known IE bug. If I had a penny for every time I'd had to fight against bugs in IE.....

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228

It's a known issue in IE. Sorry for wasting everyone's time, long story short
options.innerHTML is buggy. The work around Microsoft suggest is wrapping your  tag in a  tag. Then you can use the div.innerHTML to change the code.

```
 <div id ="IEFix">
 <select name="TOR" id="TOR">

</select>
</div>


var x ='<select name="TOR" id="TOR">\n';    
x +='<option value="MVR Only(FTE)">MVR Only(FTE)</option>\n';
    x += '</select>\n';
    IEFix.innerHTML = x;
```