# Dynamic Related Selects with jQuery, not work in IE

Tags: php, css, forms, select

So I am making a form, well I've made it and it works... but not in IE.

I have no idea why though. In every other browser but IE, the initial "make" select affects the content of the 2nd one: model. Nevertheless it does nothing in IE.

Here's the link to a page you can test it out on:  [edit - no link]

This is the method I used to update the 2nd box:

1. On the "change" event (jQuery) of the first select, javascript grabs the value selected and applies it to a variable.
2. A case select is done, matching the new variable to a set amount of potential options to be inserted via the .innerHTML property of the 2nd select.
3. A default value of "-- Please Select Model --" has been installed too within the JavaScript, yet not even this shows up in IE either. (this leads me to believe there should be a quick fix that solves the entire issue)

Via PHP, the quick inquire form is "inserted", but you can still see all the code if you "View Source" on the page.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not seeing `option` tags in IE under the `select` for the MAKE. I am guessing you do not have default tags, and FF is adding them automatically but IE is not. Do you explicitly call them out in your code? EDIT: Okay, I see your `default`. I found this http://domscripting.com/blog/display/99 that may be useful for your solution.

The gist of it is setting innerHTML only in IE is buggy. The link gives a solution. I suggest making the `option` element, setting its innerHTML, then placing it in the `select` element (that seems to be the process they say to use).

Also found similar solution here: [Setting innerHtml of a selection box in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121507/problem-with-setting-innerhtml-of-a-selection-box-in-ie)

Comment: `                                case 'Aston Martin':



                                    modelplace.innerHTML = "<option value='DB9'>DB9</option> <option value='DBS'>DBS</option> <option value='V12'>V12</option> <option value='V8'>V8</option>";



                                    break;

`