# JQuery - dynamic selects and options not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, html-select

I have a dynamic select that needs to be driven off another select, but I cannot seem to get it working in IE (using IE9). I've seen this post here but (unless I'm not understanding it) this didn't seem to help: [Dynamic Related Selects with jQuery, not work in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004365/dynamic-related-selects-with-jquery-not-work-in-ie).

I've really simplified it so that it's easy to understand the problem. I have 2 selects, and 1 drives the other. So, when you select something in the first one, the second one changes. For this example I'm just adding a new item to the select and even this doesn't work in IE:

```
var mydiv = $("#testdiv");
$("<select id='f1'>").appendTo(mydiv);
$("<select id='f2'>").appendTo(mydiv);
$("#f1").append("<option value='1'>1</option>");
$("#f1").append("<option value='2'>2</option>");
$("#f2").append($("<option>").attr("value", "n"));
$("#f1").change(function () {
    $("#f2").append("<option value='t1'>t1</option>");
});

<div id="testdiv"></div>
```

So, in theory we should start with 2 select lists and "f2" will 1 blank option in it.

Next, select an item from "f1" and it will add a new option to "f2".

This works exactly as I want in firefox and chrome. In IE it just behaves oddly. Take this example in IE:

Scenario 1

1. I open the page and check the "f2" select. It has 1 blank value
2. I select an item in "f1"
3. I check "f2" and it still has 1 blank value

Scenario 2

1. I open the page and don't touch the "f2" select.
2. I select an item in "f1"
3. I check "f2" and it has 2 items!
4. I select another item in "f1"
5. I check "f2" and it still has 2 items?!?

So it looks like the first time I activate the select control it must do something with the existing HTML... and now that's all it's going to render from here on...

This is driving me nuts, what am I doing wrong?!?

Note: Not sure if it matters, but both of the selects are dynamically generated using javascript/jquery because I don't know their values until an async call completes.

***Updated question due to investigation through comments... Seems my last note on the dynamic creation of the objects was crucial to recreating the problem***

Comment: Try `$("<option>")` instead of `$("<option></option>")`

Comment: Yeah, tried that. In fact I was originally not closing the option but it's morphed into the above due to several attempts at fixing it!

Comment: Try to give compatibility for IE , check ur jquery code twice..because IE is very stairy about code and all..

Comment: @Bondye when I change it to that it doesn't seem to work in any browser type.

Comment: could you post your script on http://www.jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @Learner if you mean set the "compatability mode" on in IE, this doesn't make a difference. And I've gone over the code many times, can't seem to figure out the problem

Comment: `$("#fieldtype1").append("<option value="t1">t1</option>");` could be it, still like to see more code :)

Comment: Ok, so I mentioned at the bottom of my quesiton "Not sure if it matters, but both of the selects are dynamically generated using javascript/jquery..." seems this is very relevent afterall! Once I remove the dynamic generation of these controls and add them manually on to my form it all suddenly starts to work. I'm currently working on either solving it, or creating a better example for you guys to see the issue.

Comment: @Bondye Ok, definitely a bug in IE. Here's a sample of it happening on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VHPt5/2/. Added in dynamic select generation

Comment: @ConorGallagher This code dont work, try selecting in the first dropdown 1 then 2 then 1 then 2 and check your 2e dropdown box

Comment: (although, need to check it on another machine to make sure it's not a PC issue...)

Comment: @Bondye I know, that's the problem. In IE it will add rows to the #f2 select list at the start. But as soon as you view the items in the #f2 select it will now stop adding them. In firefox it seems to work fine.

Comment: Fixed jsfiddle as I pasted in too many lines by mistake: http://jsfiddle.net/VHPt5/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Read on a few websites about some bugs with selects in IE and having to use divs as a workaround. So the solution is to repost the html in the div each time you want to refresh the list. Something like this:

```
var mydiv = $("#testdiv");
var mydiv2 = $("#testdiv2");
$("<select id='f1'>").appendTo(mydiv);
$("<select id='f2'>").appendTo(mydiv2);
$("#f1").append("<option value='1'>1</option>");
$("#f1").append("<option value='2'>2</option>");
$("#f2").append($("<option>").attr("value", "n"));
$("#f1").change(function () {
    var tempdiv = $("<div>");
    $("#f2").append("<option value='t1'>t1</option>");
    $("#f2").appendTo(tempdiv);
    $("#testdiv2").html($(tempdiv).html());
});

...

<div id="testdiv"></div>
<div id="testdiv2"></div>
```

The important part being "testdiv2" and populating it with the html from "tempdiv". Might be a neater way to do this but in the mean time the above works for me. Here's a working solution in jsfiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/VHPt5/4/

**Update**

Also, a slightly different way to achieve the same thing as posted in a comment by @Ingenator in a different answer below. Rather than replacing the HTML like this:

```
$("#f2").appendTo(tempdiv);
$("#testdiv2").html($(tempdiv).html());
```

You can clear the original div and re-append it:

```
$("#testdiv2").clear();
$("#f2").appendTo($("#testdiv2"));
```

Ultimately, the same solution, but removing the need to generate a tempdiv in order to replace the html of the first div.

Solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/cAr57/3/

Answer (score 8):

I have discovered another, easier work-around.

Set the options of the dynamically created select using append() or html(), then simply hide() and show() the select.

```
var mydiv = $("#testdiv");
$("<select id='f1'>").appendTo(mydiv);
$("<select id='f2'>").appendTo(mydiv);
$("#f1").append("<option value='1'>1</option>");
$("#f1").append("<option value='2'>2</option>");
$("#f2").append($("<option>").attr("value", "n"));
$("#f1").change(function () {
    $("#f2").append("<option value='t1'>t1</option>").hide().show();
});

<div id="testdiv"></div>
```

Comment: This worked but I don't really like it or know why it works but thank you for your answer.

Comment: A neater version of my answer so gets a vote from me.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#fieldtype1").append($('<option />', { 'text': 'n', 'value': 'n' }));

        $("#field1").on('change', function () {
            $("#fieldtype1").html('');

            var data = [{ 'name': '1', 'value': '1' }, { 'name': '2', 'value': '2' }, { 'name': '3', 'value': '3' }, { 'name': '4', 'value': '4'}]

            $.each(data, function (i, entity) {
                $("#fieldtype1").append($('<option />', { 'text': entity.name, 'value': entity.value }));
            });

            $("#fieldtype1").trigger('change');
        });
    });



<select id="field1">
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<select id="fieldtype1">
</select>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve my problem, but I think it's down to the complexity of my jquery. I may have to update my question to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

i got it to work using jquery clone:

```
$("#f2").append("<option value='t1'>t1</option>");
var $temp = $("#f2").clone();
$("#f2").html($temp.html());
```

Your answer helped me but i think because my select was in a modal it acted weird and this is the only way i could get it to work in IE. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I'll keep this in mind if I come across this problem

Answer (score -1):

The reason it's not working on IE is because you're trying to insert a select element into a select element, it makes sense, try not to add the select tag only the new options.

```
<td>
<select id='dinamicSelect'>
    <option value='2'>dinamicOption1</option>
    <option value='4'>dinamicOption2</option>
</select>
</td>
```

and the jquery

```
$('#dinamicSelect').html("<select><option value='123'>newOption</option></select>"); //won't work on IE

$('#dinamicSelect').html("<option value='123'>newOption</option>"); //Works
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't work. The problem occurs when you dynamically create the selects as opposed to having them pre-created in HTML. If you read the original question, in particular the note at the end, you'll notice that I'm generating the select elements using jQuery. This is actually quite pivotal as to what was causing the problem. Check out this jsfiddle simulation in both IE and Chrome/Firefox to see the issue (Change the value in the first select list more than 1 time and you'll notice it never updates after the first time the event fires): http://jsfiddle.net/tRjVY/2/

Comment: Ok, got it, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cAr57/3/) is what you want, the problem with the append is when you change many times the select options they increase like (t1 t1 t1) in [your example](http://jsfiddle.net/VHPt5/4/), hope this helps man.

Comment: The "t1" being added repeatedly wasn't the bug. T1 being added is just sample code to show that it would correctly add "T1" in chrome, but not add it in IE. Also, your edit to my jsfiddle does almost exactly what my original answer suggests. The only difference being I replace the html of the div, but you clear the div and re-append the select to it. The important point of the solution being you have to **reset** the contents of the div in order to get the jquery to work in IE. I will share your jsfiddle in my answer all the same to show people a second option.