# Internet Explorer doesn't work with JavaScript function based on php generated select option values

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, select

I've got an Internet Explorer problem with JavaScript function based on php generated select option values. I searched a little bit and I think the problem is similar with those

[Setting innerHtml of a selection box in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121507/problem-with-setting-innerhtml-of-a-selection-box-in-ie)

[Internet explorer not showing <option> value on chain select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062269/internet-explorer-not-showing-option-value-on-chain-select).

I tried different thing basing on those solutions, but with no success. 
My application works like this:

- I've got an nesting select in my HTML file:

  ```
  <div id="selectCountry" class="infobox_map">
      <p align="center"><b>Selection relating to Country:</b></p>
      <div id="country-navigation">
          <select id="first-choice" size="1" style="width: 234px" onclick="zoomToCountry(value); fillCountryInfo(value)"> 
              <option selected value="base">Choose a Country</option>
              <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
              <option value="India">India</option>
              <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>            
              <option value="Tanzania">United Republic of Tanzania</option>
          </select>   
      </div>
      <div id="project_navigation">                 
          <select id="second-choice" size="1" style="width: 234px" onclick="zoomToProject(value)">
              <option selected value="base">Select a project</option>
              <option>Projects</option>
          </select>                   
      </div>  
  </div>
  ```

The associated JavaScript function looks like this:

```
        $(function() {

        $("#first-choice").change(function() {
            $("#factbook").load("factbook.php?choice=" + $("#first-choice").val());
            $("#second-choice").load("select_country.php?choice=" + $("#first-choice").val());
        });

        $("#first-choice-proj").change(function() {
            $("#second-choice-proj").load("select_project.php?choice_proj=" + $("#first-choice-proj").val());
        });         
    });
```

So I've got two selects. When the first select (country) is done, I'm using Php to connect to a database and generate the second select (projects). This works fine, but another JavaScript function ("zoomToProject()"), which uses the generated values

```
<select id="second-choice" size="1" style="width: 234px" onclick="zoomToProject(value)">
```

doesn't work! The application works fine in Firefox, Chrome and IE 9, but IE 8 failes, because the function doesn't get the required parameter"value".

Is there anybody with an advice or an idea to this?

Cheers,
D. Stroeer

Ok, thanks for your quick response! I'm using jquery-1.3.2.
And this is the code of the "zoomToProject()" function:

```
function zoomToProject(value) {
xval = wfs_climate.getFeaturesByAttribute('name', value);
yval = wfs_climate.getFeaturesByAttribute('name', value);   
xcoord = xval[0].geometry.x;
ycoord = yval[0].geometry.y;        
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(xcoord,ycoord), 10);
```

}

Comment: you should retag your question for jQuery. You should also specify what version of jQuery you are using.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to have both click and change listeners on the element Probably best to just use change. And if you want to pass the value of the select, use `zoomToProject(this.value)`.

Comment: I think the "zoomToProject()" function code is pretty important, if that's what's not working. (Well, seems like it; it's not clear how *any* browser would get the element value via that "click" handler setup.)

Comment: You're using a version of jQuery that was released **before** IE8 was released.

Comment: Using jquery-1.7.2 doesn't help...

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to use the load function but its a lot my dynamic to use ajax together with json, like this:

index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Populating select box with ajax data</title>
    <script
      src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
      $(function()
      {
        $.get('get_country_codes.php', function(codes)
        {
          var select = $('#country_codes');

          for (var i = 0; i < codes.length; i++)
          {
            var code = codes[i];
            var option = $('<option/>');

            option.val(code.id);
            option.text(code.text);

            select.append(option);
          }
        }, 'json');
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="country_codes"></select>  
  </body>
</html>
```

get_country_codes.php:

```
<?
    $arr = array();

    $obj = new StdClass();
    $obj->id = 213;
    $obj->text = "Algeria";
    $arr[] = $obj;

    $obj = new StdClass();
    $obj->id = 46;
    $obj->text = "Sweden";
    $arr[] = $obj;

    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

and maybe your problems would go away with such a solution.